# How can I assert that require() was called in my React component test?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, mocha.js

Each of my React components have their own css file, and I'm trying to figure out a way that I can assert that each of my components required the correct css file (in the interest of getting 100% code coverage).

I'm using webpack, which allows you to require css files in React components provided you have `style-loader` and `css-loader` installed.  It looks something like this:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Component extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        require('../css/component.css');
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="component">
                Test Component
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

This is working just fine, each component has the correct styles when loaded into a browser, but I can't seem to figure out a way to write my Mocha tests to account for these `require()` calls.

Is there any way that I can mock out `require()` and assert that it was called exactly one time with the correct argument for each of my React components?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to test webpack… Why not just `import '../css/component.css'` at the beginning of the file? Actually results would be roughly the same(in case when you have external css file - it would be exactly the same. in the case when injecting style tags in head - all styles would be downloaded as before, but would be injected before first component render)…

Comment: Unfortunately, there's a difference between requiring the files in `componentDidMount` and simply using `import` at the top.  I don't actually want these files to exist within the scope of my tests, and using `import` is doing exactly that.  If I were able to mock the `require` function, I would be able to assert that these files are making their way into production, without having to expose them to my tests.

Comment: Another thing that might be worth mentioning - I'm using Material Design Lite as a css framework for my components, and one of the files that I need to `require` is a JavaScript file that allows MDL to work when loaded to the browser.  If I move my `require` calls to the top of my component, instead of inside of `componentDidMount`, Mocha will try to 'test' this file, which causes the entire test suite to fail.